# in_array still gets the company id even though I put a check

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I have the following code for the array below

```
$arrCompany = array();
foreach($users as $k => $user){



    if(!in_array($user['User']['company_id'], $arrCompany)){
        $arrCompany['company'][] = $user['User']['company_id'];
        }else{}
        }
```

what I am trying to do is just have one entery of company id so I can add users under it but for some reasons its not working

here is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [company_id] => 20
                    [type] => 
                )


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [company_id] => 21
                    [type] => 
                )


        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [company_id] => 22
                    [type] => 
                )


        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 14
                    [company_id] => 21
                    [type] => 
                )


        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 15
                    [company_id] => 22
                    [type] => 
                )



        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 16
                    [company_id] => 21
                    [type] => 
                )


                )

        )

)
```

when I do var_dump...i get this

```
Array
(
    [company] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 21
            [2] => 22
            [3] => 21
            [4] => 22
            [5] => 21
        )

)
```

you can see the company has been repeated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arrCompany = array('company'=>array());

foreach($users as $k => $user){
    if(!in_array($user['User']['company_id'], $arrCompany['company'])){
        $arrCompany['company'][] = $user['User']['company_id'];
        }
   }
```